# Styled components transitions animations not working

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, styled-components

How do I make the button change styling using transition? Right now Reactjs rerenders the component and does not show any animations for the button

```
<S.Button onClick={() => setActive(!isActive)} isActive={isActive}>
            {/* {isActive ? 'Daily stats' : 'All time stats'} */}
            asd
        </S.Button>
```

```
export const Button = styled.button<{ isActive: boolean }>`
    font-family: ${({ theme }) => theme.font.family.book};
    background-color: ${({ isActive, theme }) =>
        isActive ? '#cae8ee' : theme.color.white};
    border: 1px solid
        ${({ isActive, theme }) => (isActive ? theme.color.primary : '#f0f0f0')};
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

    &::before {
        content: '';
        background-color: ${({ isActive, theme }) =>
            isActive ? theme.color.primary : '#f0f0f0'};
        left: ${({ isActive }) => (isActive ? '150px' : '2px')};
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
`;
```

I found the issue to be the useEffect hook that fetches data on button press. Therefore, it rerenders the button without showing any animations.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (statsButtonActive) {
            fetchDailyData();
        } else {
            fetchAllTimeData();
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [statsButtonActive]);
```

Are there any solutions to stop rerendering the button?

Comment: Can you please test [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-shaw-z5jm6z?file=/src/App.js)?  I can't see any issue currently, can you please provide more context?

Comment: I have updated the question, it works when I remove the useEffect hook

Comment: Is this happening only when you've got the `React.StrictMode`?

Comment: tried with both modes, still did not find a solution for this